# iMX6Q NAND Boot issue in WinCE

Tags: c, visual-studio, embedded, storage, windows-ce

I'm trying to boot `eboot.nb0` from NAND. (Micron, `MT29F4G08ABBDA`) in WinCE7.
Processor: `i.MX6Q`

I have successfully booted `u-boot.bin` from NAND using `kobs-ng tool` in linux.
Also, if i use modified `eboot.nb0` instead of `u-boot.bin` in `kobs`, it is booting without any problem.

But when i use `MFGTool` (in WinCE) for flashing `eboot.nb0`, it is not booting.

Following is the nanddump output when i am using `kobs` (linux) for flashing:

FCB:

```
0x00000000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cf fc ff ff
0x00000010: 46 43 42 20 00 00 00 01 50 3c 19 06 00 00 00 00
0x00000020: 00 08 00 00 40 08 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x00000030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 02 00 00
0x00000040: 00 02 00 00 04 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
0x00000050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x00000060: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x00000070: 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 0b 00 00 01 01 00 00
0x00000080: 01 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 cf 07 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x00000090: 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x000000a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x000000b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x000000c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

DBBT:

```
0x00080000: 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 44 42
0x00080010: 42 54 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x00080020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x00080030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

and `eboot.nb0` at Page 200.

Here, why we are getting first 12 bytes as zeros? (`METADATA_SIZE` is set to 10). Why two additional zeros?

In WinCE (Using MFGTool):

FCB:
[Metadata: `ff ff ff ff ff ff fe ff ff ff` ] (only 10 bytes of metadata)

```
75      b8      fe      ff
46      43      42      20
0       0       0       1
50      3c      19      6
0       0       0       0
0       8       0       0
40      8       0       0
40      0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
4       0       0       0
0       2       0       0
0       2       0       0
4       0       0       0
a       0       0       0
3       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
d8      f9      8a      d9
11      0       0       0
0       2       0       0
40      3       0       0
40      1       0       0
40      1       0       0
0       1       0       0
cf      7       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       8       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
44      cd      ab      ef
d4      84      a9      ef
ff      ff      ff      ff
ff      ff      ff      ff
ff      ff      ff      ff
```

DBBT:

```
0       0       0       0
44      42      42      54
0       0       0       1
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
```

and `eboot.nb0` at `200` page.

Following is the nandtype info structure:

```
//MT29F4G08ABBDAHC
    {
       {NAND, 4096, 2048 * 64, 64, 2048},           //FlashInfo   fi;
       {0x2C, 0xAC, 0x90, 0x15},                    //BYTE        NANDCode[NANDID_LENGTH]
        3,                                          //BYTE        NumBlockCycles
        5,                                          //BYTE        ChipAddrCycleNum
        8,                                          //BYTE        DataWidth
        1,                                          //BYTE        BBMarkNum
        {0},                                        //BYTE        BBMarkPage
        6,                                          //BYTE        StatusBusyBit
        0,                                          //BYTE        StatusErrorBit
        64,                                         //WORD        SpareDataLength
        0x70,                                       //BYTE        CmdReadStatus
        0x00,                                       //BYTE        CmdRead1
        0x30,                                       //BYTE        CmdRead2
        0x90,                                       //BYTE        CmdReadId
        0xff,                                       //BYTE        CmdReset
        0x80,                                       //BYTE        CmdWrite1
        0x10,                                       //BYTE        CmdWrite2
        0x60,                                       //BYTE        CmdErase1
        0xD0,                                       //BYTE        CmdErase2
        {80, 60, 25, 6}                            //NANDTiming  timings
}
```

Following is the BootBlock structure:

```
typedef struct _BootBlockStruct_t
{
    UINT32    m_u32Checksum;         //!< First fingerprint in first byte.
    UINT32    m_u32FingerPrint;      //!< 2nd fingerprint at byte 4.
    UINT32    m_u32Version;          //!< 3rd fingerprint at byte 8.
    union
    {
        struct
        {         
            NAND_Timing_t   m_NANDTiming;                   //!< Optimum timing parameters for Tas, Tds, Tdh in nsec.
            UINT32        m_u32Reserved;                  //mx28 needs a dword reservation

            UINT32        m_u32DataPageSize;              //!< 2048 for 2K pages, 4096 for 4K pages.
            UINT32        m_u32TotalPageSize;             //!< 2112 for 2K pages, 4314 for 4K pages.
            UINT32        m_u32SectorsPerBlock;           //!< Number of 2K sections per block.
            UINT32        m_u32NumberOfNANDs;             //!< Total Number of NANDs - not used by ROM.
            UINT32        m_u32TotalInternalDie;          //!< Number of separate chips in this NAND.
            UINT32        m_u32CellType;                  //!< MLC or SLC.
            UINT32        m_u32EccBlockNEccType;         //!< Type of ECC, can be one of BCH-0-20
            UINT32        m_u32EccBlock0Size;             //!< Number of bytes for Block0 - BCH
            UINT32        m_u32EccBlockNSize;             //!< Block size in bytes for all blocks other than Block0 - BCH
            UINT32        m_u32EccBlock0EccType;         //!< Ecc level for Block 0 - BCH
            UINT32        m_u32MetadataBytes;             //!< Metadata size - BCH
            UINT32        m_u32NumEccBlocksPerPage;       //!< Number of blocks per page for ROM use - BCH
            UINT32        m_u32EccBlockNEccLevelSDK;      //!< Type of ECC, can be one of BCH-0-20
            UINT32        m_u32EccBlock0SizeSDK;          //!< Number of bytes for Block0 - BCH
            UINT32        m_u32EccBlockNSizeSDK;          //!< Block size in bytes for all blocks other than Block0 - BCH
            UINT32        m_u32EccBlock0EccLevelSDK;      //!< Ecc level for Block 0 - BCH
            UINT32        m_u32NumEccBlocksPerPageSDK;    //!< Number of blocks per page for SDK use - BCH
            UINT32        m_u32MetadataBytesSDK;          //!< Metadata size - BCH
            UINT32        m_u32EraseThreshold;            //!< To set into BCH_MODE register.
            UINT32        m_u32BootPatch;                 //!< 0 for normal boot and 1 to load patch starting next to FCB.
            UINT32        m_u32PatchSectors;              //!< Size of patch in sectors.
            UINT32        m_u32Firmware1_startingSector;  //!< Firmware image starts on this sector.
            UINT32        m_u32Firmware2_startingSector;  //!< Secondary FW Image starting Sector.
            UINT32        m_u32SectorsInFirmware1;        //!< Number of sectors in firmware image.
            UINT32        m_u32SectorsInFirmware2;        //!< Number of sector in secondary FW image.
            UINT32        m_u32DBBTSearchAreaStartAddress;//!< Page address where dbbt search area begins
            UINT32        m_u32BadBlockMarkerByte;        //!< Byte in page data that have manufacturer marked bad block marker, this will
                                                            //!< bw swapped with metadata[0] to complete page data.
            UINT32        m_u32BadBlockMarkerStartBit;    //!< For BCH ECC sizes other than 8 and 16 the bad block marker does not start
                                                            //!< at 0th bit of m_u32BadBlockMarkerByte. This field is used to get to the
                                                            //!< start bit of bad block marker byte with in m_u32BadBlockMarkerByte.
            UINT32        m_u32BBMarkerPhysicalOffset;    //!< FCB value that gives byte offset for bad block marker on physical NAND page.




  UINT32  m_u32BCHType;
  UINT32  m_u32TMTiming2_ReadLatency;
  UINT32  m_u32TMTiming2_PreambleDelay;
  UINT32  m_u32TMTiming2_CEDelay;
  UINT32  m_u32TMTiming2_PostambleDelay;
  UINT32  m_u32TMTiming2_CmdAddPause;
  UINT32  m_u32TMTiming2_DataPause;
  UINT32  m_u32TMSpeed;
  UINT32  m_u32TMTiming1_BusyTimeout;
  UINT32  m_u32DISBBM;
  UINT32  m_u32BBMark_spare_offset;
  UINT32  m_u32Onfi_sync_enable;
  UINT32  m_u32Onfi_sync_speed;
  UINT32  m_u32Onfi_syncNANDData;
  UINT32  m_u32DISBB_Search;


        } FCB_Block;
        struct
        {                         
            UINT32        m_u32NumberBB;                    //!< # Bad Blocks stored in this table for NAND0.
            UINT32        m_u32Number2KPagesBB;           //!< Bad Blocks for NAND0 consume this # of 2K pages.
        } DBBT_Block;
    };
} BootBlockStruct_t;

Following are the values i'm assigning (Which are equal to linux):
FCB
  m_u32FingerPrint = 0x20424346
  m_u32Version = 0x01000000
  m_u32Reserved = 0
  m_NANDTiming.m_u8DataSetup = 80
  m_NANDTiming.m_u8DataHold = 60
  m_NANDTiming.m_u8AddressSetup = 25
  m_NANDTiming.m_u8DSAMPLE_TIME = 6
  m_u32PageDataSize = 2048
  m_u32TotalPageSize = 2112
  m_u32SectorsPerBlock = 64
  m_u32NumberOfNANDs = 0
  m_u32TotalInternalDie = 0
  m_u32CellType = 0
  m_u32EccBlockNEccType = 4
  m_u32EccBlock0Size = 512
  m_u32EccBlockNSize = 512
  m_u32EccBlock0EccType = 4
  m_u32MetadataBytes = 10
  m_u32NumEccBlocksPerPage = 3
  m_u32EccBlockNEccLevelSDK = 0
  m_u32EccBlock0SizeSDK = 0
  m_u32EccBlockNSizeSDK = 0
  m_u32EccBlock0EccLevelSDK = 0
  m_u32NumEccBlocksPerPageSDK = 0
  m_u32MetadataBytesSDK = 0
  m_u32EraseThreshold = 0
  m_u32Firmware1_startingPage = 512
  m_u32Firmware2_startingPage = 2816
  m_u32PagesInFirmware1 = 91
  m_u32PagesInFirmware2 = 91
  m_u32DBBTSearchAreaStartAddress = 256
  m_u32BadBlockMarkerByte = 1999
  m_u32BadBlockMarkerStartBit = 0
  m_u32BBMarkerPhysicalOffset = 2048
  m_u32BCHType = 0
  m_NANDTMTiming.m_u32TMTiming2_ReadLatency = 0
  m_NANDTMTiming.m_u32TMTiming2_PreambleDelay = 0
  m_NANDTMTiming.m_u32TMTiming2_CEDelay = 0
  m_NANDTMTiming.m_u32TMTiming2_PostambleDelay = 0
  m_NANDTMTiming.m_u32TMTiming2_CmdAddPause = 0
  m_NANDTMTiming.m_u32TMTiming2_DataPause = 0
  m_NANDTMTiming.m_u32TMSpeed = 0
  m_NANDTMTiming.m_u32TMTiming1_BusyTimeout = 0
  m_u32DISBBM = 0
DBBT
  m_u32Checksum = 0x00000000
  m_u32FingerPrint = 0x54424244
  m_u32Version = 0x01000000
```

In WinCE, it is not at all booting.

Where is the mistake?
If metadata size difference is the problem , how i can solve it? ( I have also tried by changing `METADATA_SIZE` = 12, which increases metadata size, but not booting.)
What are those two extra bytes in linux (kobs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Eboot is booting from NAND now.

Correct data to be written for booting:

FCB:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 cf fc ff ff
46 43 42 20 00 00 00 01 50 3c 19 06 00 00 00 00
00 08 00 00 40 08 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 02 00 00
00 02 00 00 04 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 0b 00 00 01 01 00 00
01 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 cf 07 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1b 0c 06 06
10 1f 03 07 00 00 00 1c 0f 17 1f 05 00 00 00 00
00 19 00 00 15 19 00 00 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 13 00 00 00 00 16 00 00
00 16 00 00 13 00 00 00 0f 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 13 00 00 1c 1c 00 00
1c 1c 00 00 00 1c 00 00 1b 19 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 19 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

DBBT:

```
00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 44 42
42 54 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 74 9c 34 5d ed 4b
6d 24 4d 04 d8 e4 48 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

EBOOT:

```
e5 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c2 02 c8 c7 39 aa
0c a8 ef 77 29 f1 78 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 d1 00 20 40 60 74 90 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 40 74 90 00 00 74 90 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 d1 00 20 40 00 20 04 80 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 54 74 90 00 20 74 90 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 70 90 00 00 10 00 00 01 00 00 00
00 0c 04 80 00 04 08 00 00 0c 04 80 00 04 08 00
00 00 00 00 ff 40 2d e9 00 70 a0 e1 09 06 50 e3
28 30 1f e5 00 30 80 85 18 36 9f e5 00 30 81 85
42 3e a0 e3 00 30 82 85 40 40 4f e2 40 50 4f e2
40 60 4f e2 00 06 9f e5 00 10 e0 e3 68 20 a0 e3
02 10 80 e7 00 10 e0 e3 6c 20 a0 e3 02 10 80 e7
00 10 e0 e3 70 20 a0 e3 02 10 80 e7 00 10 e0 e3
74 20 a0 e3 02 10 80 e7 00 10 e0 e3 78 20 a0 e3
02 10 80 e7 00 10 e0 e3 7c 20 a0 e3 02 10 80 e7
00 10 e0 e3 80 20 a0 e3 02 10 80 e7 00 10 e0 e3
84 20 a0 e3 02 10 80 e7 9c 05 9f e5 9c 15 9f e5
18 20 a0 e3 02 10 80 e7 94 05 9f e5 94 15 9f e5
94 25 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 88 15 9f e5 5b 2e a0 e3
02 10 80 e7 7c 15 9f e5 80 25 9f e5 02 10 80 e7
70 15 9f e5 78 25 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 64 15 9f e5
70 25 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 58 15 9f e5 68 25 9f e5
02 10 80 e7 4c 15 9f e5 60 25 9f e5 02 10 80 e7
40 15 9f e5 17 2d a0 e3 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3
4c 25 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3 44 25 9f e5
02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3 3c 25 9f e5 02 10 80 e7
38 10 a0 e3 52 2e a0 e3 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3
28 25 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3 51 2e a0 e3
02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3 14 25 9f e5 02 10 80 e7
38 10 a0 e3 0c 25 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3
04 25 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 00 15 9f e5 00 25 9f e5
02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3 f8 24 9f e5 02 10 80 e7
38 10 a0 e3 f0 24 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3
e8 24 9f e5 2f 4b 52 82 fe b2 58 65 c4 a5 96 f4
3e 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3 59 2e a0 e3 02 10 80
e7 38 10 a0 e3 d4 24 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 00 10 a0
e3 cc 24 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3 c4 24 9f
e5 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3 5a 2e a0 e3 02 10 80
e7 38 10 a0 e3 b0 24 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0
e3 a8 24 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3 a0 24 9f
e5 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3 98 24 9f e5 02 10 80
e7 38 10 a0 e3 7a 2e a0 e3 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0
e3 84 24 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3 7c 24 9f
e5 02 10 80 e7 38 10 a0 e3 74 24 9f e5 02 10 80
e7 38 10 a0 e3 6c 24 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 02 18 a0
e3 75 2e a0 e3 02 10 80 e7 00 10 a0 e3 58 24 9f
e5 02 10 80 e7 02 18 a0 e3 50 24 9f e5 02 10 80
e7 38 10 a0 e3 48 24 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 02 17 a0
e3 40 24 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 3c 04 9f e5 02 19 a0
e3 1c 10 80 e5 02 19 a0 e3 30 24 9f e5 02 10 80
e7 2c 14 9f e5 5c 18 80 e5 24 14 9f e5 24 24 9f
e5 02 10 80 e7 20 14 9f e5 00 18 80 e5 18 14 9f
e5 12 2b a0 e3 02 10 80 e7 01 15 a0 e3 90 18 80
e5 01 15 a0 e3 04 24 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 00 14 9f
e5 00 24 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 02 1b a0 e3 b8 18 80
e5 02 1b a0 e3 f0 23 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 ec 13 9f
e5 1c 18 80 e5 e4 13 9f e5 20 18 80 e5 e0 13 9f
e5 24 18 80 e5 d4 13 9f e5 28 18 80 e5 d0 13 9f
e5 d0 23 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 c4 13 9f e5 c8 23 9f
e5 02 10 80 e7 b8 13 9f e5 c0 23 9f e5 02 10 80
e7 ac 13 9f e5 b8 23 9f e5 02 10 80 e7 b4 13 9f
e5 2c 18 80 e5 ac 13 9f e5 30 18 80 e5 a4 13 9f
e5 34 18 80 e5 9c 13 9f e5 38 18 80 e5 94 13 9f

.

.

.
```